# Tenho um código de geolocalização, porém o chrome não me da autorização para executa-lo

Tags: javascript, geolocalização, google-maps-api-3

Gostaria de saber, seu eu tenho que dar algum tipo de permissão, para que o código funcione no Chrome, pois no mozila ele consegue me dar a localização.
**Segue o código abaixo**`

```
function writeAddressName(latLng) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
    "location": latLng

    },
    function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
      else
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Unable to retrieve your address" + "<br />";
    });
  }



  function geolocationSuccess(position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    // Escreva o endereço da localização
    writeAddressName(userLatLng);





    // Coloque o marcador na posição do usuario
      new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon:'img/aqui',
      position: userLatLng

    });


    // Desenhe um círculo em torno da posição do usuário para ter uma idéia da precisão de localização atual
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      center: userLatLng,
      radius: 500,
      map: map,
      fillColor: '#0000FF',
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      strokeColor: '#0000FF',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,


    });
    map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
  }

  function geolocationError(positionError) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />";
  }

  function geolocateUser() {
    // Verifica se o navegador suportar a Geolocation API
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
      var positionOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds

      };
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, positionOptions);
    }
    else
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API";
  }

  window.onload = geolocateUser;
```

Comment: getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transformando o comentário do Pedro Augusto em resposta. O pessoal do Chromium (projeto no qual o Chrome é baseado) não mais aceita que certas funcionalidades funcionem sobre HTTP. Você só vai conseguir usar em cima de HTTPS, por motivos de segurança.

Fonte: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

> We want to start applying the concepts in https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/ to features that have already shipped and which do not meet the (new, not present at the time) requirements. In particular, this approximately requires that powerful features only be accessible on "secure origins" (such as HTTPS)

Tradução livre:

> Nós queremos começar a aplicar os conceitos em https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/ nas funcionalidades que já foram lançadas e que não se adequam aos novos requisitos (que não estavam presentes quando as funcionalidades foram lançadas). Em particular, isso significa que funcionalidades poderosas [sic] só serão acessíveis a partir de origens seguras (tais como HTTPS).

Em outras palavras: você vai precisar de um certificado SSL no seu servidor para continuar a usar geolocalização com o Chrome da forma como está fazendo.

Comment: Obrigado, tirou as palavras da minha boca :)

Comment: Complementando, caso considere utilizar SSL, tente o openssl ou compre algum certificado. Várias empresas vendem e não são tão caros.

Comment: Rolou uma cena de Mochileiro das Galáxias nessa história do Chromium. `"Como assim, esse negócio não funciona mais em HTTP? Vocês deviam ter avisado!"` Aí você entra na página do link e eles dizem que deixaram o recado num *post it* no porão da prefeitura (`"We (Chrome Security) originally sent this out to various browser development mailing lists"`)

Comment: Vale lembrar que com [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) e outras implementações baseadase em ACME nao tem mais desculpa pra uma pessoa não ter HTTPS hoje. É gratuito, automático, padronizado e bem aceito.